# Sort by values of documents in nested arrays in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection called Objects. Each Object document has a nested array of documents called properties. Each property document has a name and a value.

For example, let's say I have these two objects, each having two properties (height and width). How would I sort the objects by height?

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "height",
      "value": 170
    },
    {
      "name": "width",
      "value": 200
    },
  ]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "height",
      "value": 100
    },
    {
      "name": "width",
      "value": 300
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can't you just let mongodb return the array and sort it afterwards?

Comment: No, the collection is too large to pull and sort in the application.

Comment: You can use MongoDB's [`aggregation`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to achieve this.  I'll post a sample query shortly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In most cases, MongoDB's [`aggregation framework`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) is your friend whenever you are dealing with arrays.  Take a look at the [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator that can be use to break the array into individual documents.  I've posted a sample query below to sort the documents by `height`. Note that you can use the `$project` operator in the aggregation pipeline to better format the results.

```js
db.objects.aggregate([
    // De-normalize the 'properties' array
    {$unwind:"$properties"}, 
    // Filter for only height
    {$match:{"properties.name":"height"}},
    // Sort by 'height' in ascending order.  Use -1 for descending 
    {$sort:{"properties.value":1}}
])
```

**EDIT:** One way to keep the `properties` element intact is to make a copy of it just to be used for sorting.  An example is below:

```js
db.objects.aggregate([
    // Make a copy of the 'properties' element
    {$project:{properties:1, sortfield:"$properties"}}, 
    {$unwind:"$sortfield"}, 
    {$match:{"sortfield.name":"height"}}, 
    {$sort:{"sortfield.value":1}}, 
    // Get rid of 'sortfield' 
    {$project:{properties:1}}
])
```

Comment: It is returning the objects without the rest of the properties though (only height is there, but not width). Is there a way to include them in the results, or do I need to pull those with subsequent queries?

Comment: @Marjan, I've updated my answer to include another query which will keep the rest of the properties intact.